# How can I get input from an Xbox One controller in Python?

Tags: python

I want to add controller support to games I make in Python, but I cannot find any Xbox One controller input module for Python. I need specifically Xbox One controller support. Thanks!

Comment: I also gave an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51136726/read-xbox-one-controller-inputs-with-python/56528698#56528698

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `pygame` as it reads joysticks (with the [`pygame.joystick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/joystick.html) class), it really doesn't matter what type of controller you use for `pygame`. An example is we want to make python print "A Has Been Pressed", when we press the 'a' button.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
joysticks = []
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
keepPlaying = True

# for al the connected joysticks
for i in range(0, pygame.joystick.get_count()):
    # create an Joystick object in our list
    joysticks.append(pygame.joystick.Joystick(i))
    # initialize the appended joystick (-1 means last array item)
    joysticks[-1].init()
    # print a statement telling what the name of the controller is
    print ("Detected joystick "),joysticks[-1].get_name(),"'"
while keepPlaying:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # The 0 button is the 'a' button, 1 is the 'b' button, 2 is the 'x' button, 3 is the 'y' button
        if event.button == 0:
            print ("A Has Been Pressed")
```

Comment: I get the following error:
 `if event.button == 0:


AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'button'`

Comment: No, it does matter what type of controller you use. Microsoft's Xbox controllers simply have not worked with pygame, for years.


From https://blog.thea.codes/talking-to-gamepads-without-pygame/:

"A fun thing to note - the XBox controllers don't work with this approach. They don't use a standard HID protocol and instead use a proprietary protocol. It's possible to talk to them using the higher-level APIs or with the even more low-level libusb (if you're brave)."

Comment: @FelipeMedLev not all events have the same keys. It works for my XBox One controller just fine.
<Event(1541-JoyDeviceAdded {'device_index': 0, 'guid': '030000005e040000dd02000003020000'})>
<Event(1539-JoyButtonDown {'joy': 0, 'instance_id': 0, 'button': 0})>
<Event(1540-JoyButtonUp {'joy': 0, 'instance_id': 0, 'button': 0})>

Comment: `initialize them all (-1 means loop forever)` No it doesn't? -1 means the last index.

Comment: To resolve the 'no attribute 'button' issue, comment out the `if event.botton == 0:` section, and instead, create a new mapping after you run the above code with just `print(event)`.

Answer (score 13):

The [inputs library](https://pypi.org/project/inputs/) can be used as an alternative to PyGame.

```
from inputs import get_gamepad
import math
import threading

class XboxController(object):
    MAX_TRIG_VAL = math.pow(2, 8)
    MAX_JOY_VAL = math.pow(2, 15)

    def __init__(self):

        self.LeftJoystickY = 0
        self.LeftJoystickX = 0
        self.RightJoystickY = 0
        self.RightJoystickX = 0
        self.LeftTrigger = 0
        self.RightTrigger = 0
        self.LeftBumper = 0
        self.RightBumper = 0
        self.A = 0
        self.X = 0
        self.Y = 0
        self.B = 0
        self.LeftThumb = 0
        self.RightThumb = 0
        self.Back = 0
        self.Start = 0
        self.LeftDPad = 0
        self.RightDPad = 0
        self.UpDPad = 0
        self.DownDPad = 0

        self._monitor_thread = threading.Thread(target=self._monitor_controller, args=())
        self._monitor_thread.daemon = True
        self._monitor_thread.start()


    def read(self): # return the buttons/triggers that you care about in this methode
        x = self.LeftJoystickX
        y = self.LeftJoystickY
        a = self.A
        b = self.X # b=1, x=2
        rb = self.RightBumper
        return [x, y, a, b, rb]


    def _monitor_controller(self):
        while True:
            events = get_gamepad()
            for event in events:
                if event.code == 'ABS_Y':
                    self.LeftJoystickY = event.state / XboxController.MAX_JOY_VAL # normalize between -1 and 1
                elif event.code == 'ABS_X':
                    self.LeftJoystickX = event.state / XboxController.MAX_JOY_VAL # normalize between -1 and 1
                elif event.code == 'ABS_RY':
                    self.RightJoystickY = event.state / XboxController.MAX_JOY_VAL # normalize between -1 and 1
                elif event.code == 'ABS_RX':
                    self.RightJoystickX = event.state / XboxController.MAX_JOY_VAL # normalize between -1 and 1
                elif event.code == 'ABS_Z':
                    self.LeftTrigger = event.state / XboxController.MAX_TRIG_VAL # normalize between 0 and 1
                elif event.code == 'ABS_RZ':
                    self.RightTrigger = event.state / XboxController.MAX_TRIG_VAL # normalize between 0 and 1
                elif event.code == 'BTN_TL':
                    self.LeftBumper = event.state
                elif event.code == 'BTN_TR':
                    self.RightBumper = event.state
                elif event.code == 'BTN_SOUTH':
                    self.A = event.state
                elif event.code == 'BTN_NORTH':
                    self.Y = event.state #previously switched with X
                elif event.code == 'BTN_WEST':
                    self.X = event.state #previously switched with Y
                elif event.code == 'BTN_EAST':
                    self.B = event.state
                elif event.code == 'BTN_THUMBL':
                    self.LeftThumb = event.state
                elif event.code == 'BTN_THUMBR':
                    self.RightThumb = event.state
                elif event.code == 'BTN_SELECT':
                    self.Back = event.state
                elif event.code == 'BTN_START':
                    self.Start = event.state
                elif event.code == 'BTN_TRIGGER_HAPPY1':
                    self.LeftDPad = event.state
                elif event.code == 'BTN_TRIGGER_HAPPY2':
                    self.RightDPad = event.state
                elif event.code == 'BTN_TRIGGER_HAPPY3':
                    self.UpDPad = event.state
                elif event.code == 'BTN_TRIGGER_HAPPY4':
                    self.DownDPad = event.state




if __name__ == '__main__':
    joy = XboxController()
    while True:
        print(joy.read())
```

The buttons and triggers are returned as a list in the read methode. So put in there what you need to be returned.

This is part of a script of the [Tensorkart project](https://github.com/kevinhughes27/TensorKart/blob/455d28083806814377b60567b559f97597ccd7e0/utils.py) by [bzier](https://github.com/bzier). I just removed everything that was not related to capturing the controller inputs.

Comment: Note that inputs does not support MacOS