# Read Xbox One Controller Inputs with Python

Tags: python-2.7, xbox-one

I am trying to find a way to read Xbox One controller inputs with python on a Raspberry pi. I have found a library for an Xbox 360 controller, but this doesn't seem to recognize the Xbox One controller. I am able to connect the controller to my computer. I would use a 360 controller but I need to be wireless. I am using the standard Xbox One controller that comes with the Xbox.

Comment: Hi There! Welcome to stack overflow. Can you please give us a bit more context: can you share some of the code you have tried, or a link to the library? Have you any debug information showing that the controller is talking to the pi? Its quite possible that the code for the 360 controller will not work for the One.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get input from an Xbox One controller in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46506850/how-can-i-get-input-from-an-xbox-one-controller-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

A wireless xbox 360 controller can be used with a receiver (buy it online) and installing xboxdrv with:

```
sudo apt-get install xboxdrv
```

This repository can then be used to get input https://github.com/FRC4564/Xbox Their docs explain using it.

For using an xbox one controller with python you can use the library evdev to the input values.
Here is a guide which shows every usage case:

https://diyprojects.io/python-library-evdev-raspberry-pi-use-gamepad-diy-projects-servomotor-games/#.Xa8ZR-gzaUl